# jQuery load certain element only

Tags: jquery, load, element

Using PHP a new href is created in a list. How using jQuery can we load in that new href only and not the entire container.

```
<div class="container">
<a href="" id="test1">Test 1</a>
<a href="" id="test2">Test 2</a>
<a href="" id="test3">Test 3</a>
<a href="" id="test4">Test 4</a>
</div>
```

Now we know we have created an element `#test5` with PHP, how do we load just that in at the end of this list.

Comment: What do you mean by "creating an element" in PHP?  Do you simply mean you're dynamically writing out the markup from PHP to the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code, use

```
$('.container').append('<a href="" id="test5">Test 5</a>');
```

If you need to load the data from a PHP script, use the following code:

```
$.get('http://example.com', null, 
   function(data){$('.container').append(data);}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$('div.container').append('<a href="" id="test5">Test 5</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append` or [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

```
$('<a href="" id="test5">Test 5</a>').appendTo('.container');
```

IF you receive the complete anchor tag( Ex: `<a href="soemthing.php">Test5</a`>) from an ajax request, you can simply append that.

```
$.get("fromsomefile.php",function(data){
   $(data).appendTo('.container');
});
```

If you got onlt the href(`Ex: ="sompage.php"`) value then create a link and set the `href` attribute value

```
$.get("fromsomefile.php",function(data){
   $('<a id="someDynamcId">Tes 5</a>').attr("href",data).appendTo('.container');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if I haven't got the question wrong you load just the a tag from php...I will show on the code...lets say

```
 $.post("some.php",{some:parameter},function(data){
    //data is <a href="" ></a>
    $(".container").append(data);
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

If the element is already loaded use this:

```
$('#test4').attr('href','whatever you want to change');
```